# Use value of key as part of value of another key in the same hash

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, hash, key

How use the value of a key as part of operation into value of another key in the same hash in Ruby, at the moment of declare it?

I mean something like this:

```
purchase = {product:  'phone',
            quantity: 5,
            price: 120,
            total: self.quantity * self.price
           }
```

I think this would be useful, for instance, if the value `quantity` is assigned by an external API where consumes limited queries from, so if `total` requests too, one spends two queries instead of ask for 'quantity' spending only one query.

Comment: you want when initialize hash its some values based on other keys?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you ask for is not possible during Hash declaration. You can change your code like this:

```
purchase = {}
purchase[:product]  = 'phone'
purchase[:quantity] = 5
purchase[:price]    = 120
purchase[:total]    = purchase[:quantity] * purchase[:price]
```

Or just the last line:

```
purchase = {
 product: 'phone',
 quantity: 5,
 price:    120
}
purchase[:total] = purchase[:quantity] * purchase[:price]
```

Or other silly ways that involve slightly less typing:

```
purchase = {
 product: 'phone',
 quantity: 5,
 price:    120
}.tap{ |h| h[:total] = h[:quantity] * h[:price] }
```

However, I would suggest that in a case like this you should NOT store ["denormalized" data](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Denormalization) in your hash. As `total` is dependent upon the quantity or price, if either of them changes your hash will be invalid.

You could get around this by creating a special `default_proc` on your hash that computes the total on the fly each time it is requested:

```
purchase = {
 product: 'phone',
 quantity: 5,
 price:    120
}
purchase.default_proc = ->(h,k){
  h[:quantity]*h[:price] if k==:total
}
p purchase[:total]      #=> 600
purchase[:quantity] = 7
p purchase[:total]      #=> 840
```

However, it would be more clear to create a class or Struct to do this. A Struct is less code for you:

```
Purchase = Struct.new(:product,:quantity,:price) do
  def total
    quantity * price
  end
end
purchase = Purchase.new('phone',5,120)
p purchase.total                       #=> 600
purchase.quantity = 3
p purchase.total                       #=> 360
```

However, the Struct does not ([by default](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17061970/405017)) allow keyword arguments. By writing your own class you can supply the arguments in any order, and even provide a default value:

```
class Purchase
  attr_reader :product, :price, :quantity
  def initialize(product:,price:,quantity:1) # default quantity
    @product, @price, @quantity = product, price, quantity
  end
  def total
    price*quantity
  end
end

Purchase.new(price:10, product:'shoes').total              #=> 10
Purchase.new(product:'shoes', price:10).total              #=> 10
Purchase.new(quantity:3, price:10, product:'shoes').total  #=> 30
```

Answer (score 4):

I would suggest to create a `Purchase` model that does the calculation:

```
class Purchase
  attr_reader :product, quantity, price

  def initialize(attributes = {})
    @product  = attributes[:product]
    @quantity = attributes[:quantity]
    @price    = attributes[:price]
  end

  def total 
    quantity * price
  end

  def to_h
    {
      product:  product,
      quantity: quantity,
      price:    price,
      total:    total
    }
  end
end
```

Than change your code to:

```
purchase = Purchase.new(product: 'phone', quantity: 5, price: 120).to_h
```

As a bonus: This model is easy to understand and easy to test.

Comment: May I suggest keyword arguments instead of the attributes hash?

Comment: I would prefer kwargs too. But to use required keyword arguments you need to use at least Ruby 2.1 and many developers still use older versions for various reasons.

Comment: what do you mean @Phrogz?

Comment: @IvánCortésRomero See the bottom of my answer for keyword arguments in a class, instead of relying on positional arguments. Positional (as in the Struct example of mine) results in less typing, but also less code clarity and robustness.