# Initializing Ruby Structs with Keyword arguments

Tags: ruby, struct

Ruby version: 2.3.1

It does not appear that Ruby Structs can be declared using keyword params. Is there a way to do this within `Struct`?

Example:

```
MyStruct = Struct.new(:fname, :lname)
=> MyStruct

my_struct = MyStruct.new(fname: 'first', lname: 'last')
=> <struct MyStruct fname={:fname=>"first", :lname=>"last"}, lname=nil>

my_struct.fname
=> {:fname=>"first", :lname=>"last"}

my_struct.lname
=> nil
```

Answer (score 22):

With Ruby 2.5, you can set the `keyword_init` option to `true`.

```
MyStruct = Struct.new(:fname, :lname, keyword_init: true)
# => MyStruct(keyword_init: true)
irb(main):002:0> my_struct = MyStruct.new(fname: 'first', lname: 'last')
# => #<struct MyStruct fname="first", lname="last">
```

Comment: As of Ruby 3.2+, you no longer need to specify `keyword_init: true`. Structs can automatically be initialized by keyword arguments. https://www.ruby-lang.org/en/news/2022/12/25/ruby-3-2-0-released/

Answer (score 2):

```
my_struct = MyStruct.new(fname: 'first', lname: 'last')
```

is the same as

```
my_struct = MyStruct.new({ fname: 'first', lname: 'last' })
  #=> #<struct MyStruct fname={:fname=>"first", :lname=>"last"}, lname=nil>
```

(one argument) so `fname` is set equal to the argument and `lname` is set to `nil`, in the same way that `x, y = [2]; x #=> 2; y #=> nil`.

This is because Ruby allows one to omit the braces when a hash is the argument of a method.

You may wish to search SO for related questions such as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5407940/named-parameters-in-ruby-structs).

Comment: Ok, that makes sense. However, I'm still not sure how to get the keyword arguments to work. I can pass in two hashes ie `MyStruct.new({fname: 'first'}, {lname: 'last'})` but that will give me a hash to work with rather than a string.

Comment: I seemed to have missed your 3-month-old comment. `my_struct = MyStruct.new({fname: 'first'}, {lname: 'last'}); my_struct.fname #=>  {:fname=>"first"}; my_struct.lname #=> {:lname=>"last"}`. Does that answer your question?

Comment: I wrote a gem (https://github.com/rohitpaulk/named_struct) that defines a `NamedStruct` class that inherits from Struct, and changes the initialization behavior to accept keyword arguments instead.