# What's the purpose of an anonymous struct in Ruby?

Tags: ruby

They can be defined like this

`Struct.new(:x, :y)`

But what can usefully be done with them?  Specifically, how can I create an instance of such a struct?  This doesn't work

`Struct.new(:x => 1, :y => 1)`

(you get `TypeError: can't convert Hash into String`).

I'm using Ruby 1.9.2.

UPDATE:

Good pointers so far, thanks.  I suppose the reason I asked this was that I have several times found myself wanting to do this

`Struct.new(:x => 1, :y => 1)`

just so that I can pass an object around where I can write `obj.x` instead of, say, instantiating a hash and having to write `obj[:x]`.  In this case I want the structure to be *really* anonymous - I don't want to pollute my namespace with anything by naming what is returned from the `Struct.new` call.  The closest thing to that, as already suggested is

`Struct.new(:x, :y).new(1, 1)`

But how do you like them apples?  I'm not sure I do.  Is it reasonable to expect to be able to define and instantiate an anonymous struct in one go (as part of core Ruby)?  I guess when I read the official Ruby docs on `Struct.new` I assume the word 'anonymous' allows this, but it doesn't.

Comment: This might be also interesting for you to skim through: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1177594/ruby-struct-vs-openstruct

Comment: Yeah, I found that before posting but it doesn't address anonymous structs directly.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

`Struct.new` returns a `Class`, so you can, for example, assign it to a constant like this:

```
Point = Struct.new(:x, :y)
```

or subclass it:

```
class Point < Struct.new(:x, :y)
  # custom methods here
  # ...
end
```

In both cases, you can use the resulting class like this:

```
Point.new(3, 5)
```

If you don't want to create a specific class (because you need to instantiate an object of that class only once), consider to use `OpenStruct` instead:

```
require 'ostruct'

point = OpenStruct.new(:x => 3, :y => 5)
```

Comment: +1 First explanation I've read that makes it actually sound somewhat useful.

Comment: Like the `OpenStruct` suggestion - that's most like what I expected I'd be able to do with `Struct.new`.

Answer (score 5):

You first create a struct, and then you can create instances of it. It's a way of creating data objects without having to declare a class. Basically it's the same as a hash, but it's more clean to access the objects. You can get stuff out of it by referencing it via ordinary accessor methods.

http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Struct.html

```
# Create a structure with a name in Struct
Struct.new("Customer", :name, :address)    #=> Struct::Customer
Struct::Customer.new("Dave", "123 Main")   #=> #<struct Struct::Customer name="Dave", address="123 Main">

# Create a structure named by its constant
Customer = Struct.new(:name, :address)     #=> Customer
Customer.new("Dave", "123 Main")           #=> #<struct Customer name="Dave", address="123 Main">
```

Answer (score 4):

Well, you can use Structs when you don't actually want to write a class with accessors. It's handy to just write

```
Project = Struct.new(:name)
```

instead of

```
class Project
  attr_accesor :name
end
```

As tokland pointed out correctly (thanks!), a Struct also gives you a nice #initialize method automagically. So the following is possible without any further code:

```
Project = Struct.new(:name)
p = Project.new('Quadriloptic Curves')
```

Comment: with Struct you get also an initializer. (type -> accesor -> accesor)

Answer (score 3):

I'm hot sure about purpose but `Struct.new` returns class so

```
irb(main):001:0> Struct.new(:x,:y)
=> #<Class:0x2914110>
irb(main):002:0> Struct.new(:x,:y).new(1,2)
=> #<struct x=1, y=2>
```

Comment: Yeah, that second line is either beautiful or very ugly, I can't decide!

Comment: Seems more ugly then beautiful for me. It is a violation of the law of demeter I suppose. I'm not very familiar with s Struct usage.

Answer (score 1):

`OpenStruct` is probably what you want, but I ran into a situation recently where `OpenStruct` didn't work because I needed to raise an error when trying to access an undefined attribute. `Struct` *does* this:

```
os = OpenStruct.new
os.x = 1; os.y = 2;
os.z # returns nil

s = Struct.new(:x, :y).new
s.x = 1; s.y = 2;
s.z # raises NoMethodError
```

Just something to keep in mind.

Answer (score 0):

As for creating instances:

```
User = Struct.new(:user,:password)
u = User.new("john","secret")
```