# Convert a hash into a struct

Tags: ruby

How can I convert a hash into a struct in ruby?

Given this:

```
h = { :a => 1, :b => 2 }
```

I want a struct such that:

```
s.a == 1
s.b == 2
```

Answer (score 72, accepted):

If it doesn't *specifically* have to be a `Struct` and instead can be an `OpenStruct`:

```
pry(main)> require 'ostruct'
pry(main)> s = OpenStruct.new(h)
=> #<OpenStruct a=1, b=2>
pry(main)> puts s.a, s.b
1
2
```

Comment: Be aware that OpenStructs can be incredibly slow to use. Fine for a small number of small objects, but they scale badly.

Some further info here:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1177594/ruby-struct-vs-openstruct

Comment: @AFaderDarkly I think their speed issues are well documented, but thanks.

Comment: I believe the last command should read: `pry(main)> puts s.a, s.b` or line 2 should read `pry(main)> o = OpenStruct.new(h)`

Comment: @DaveNewton: Not on this page they haven't. Or on numerous sites that recommend their use. The original question asked for a struct - it is only polite - I think - to warn of the trade-off inherent in using a different solution.

Comment: @AFaderDarkly Which is why I stated that this answer isn't a struct. And it's trivial to find performance information *if* it becomes a bottleneck. In any case, as I said, thanks, but this is a conversation you'll need to continue on your own. I offered an alternative solution.

Comment: fwiw I came to this page looking to replace OpenStruct with Struct because of performance issues. Please at least update your answer with a warning.

Comment: `Struct` raises on non-existing methods (much safer / better / clearer / simpler / etc.): https://stackoverflow.com/a/44121818/407213

Comment: @Dorian Yes, it does. But if you're unaware of what's coming in it may or may not be a better option. Shrug.

Answer (score 75):

If you already have a struct defined, and you want to instantiate an instance with a hash:

```
Person = Struct.new(:first_name, :last_name, :age)

person_hash = { first_name: "Foo", last_name: "Bar", age: 29 }

person = Person.new(*person_hash.values_at(*Person.members))

=> #<struct Person first_name="Foo", last_name="Bar", age=29>
```

Comment: Thank you! I'm designing a gem that can be invoked from a command or from outer code, each supplying options (using OptionParser or a Hash respectively). This allows easy filtering of options during initialization of my gem. And the Struct helps to "self-document" allowed options as well!

Comment: Really nice solution

Comment: In ruby > 2.0 you can do this slightly more concisely with the double splat operator (**) - `Person.new(**person_hash)`

Answer (score 60):

Since Hash key order is guaranteed in Ruby 1.9+:

```
Struct.new(*h.keys).new(*h.values)
```

Comment: Good to know. I though I read that somewhere but didn't remember where. Thanks!

Comment: This doesn't appear to work (at least in Ruby 2.2.0): `Struct.new(*h.keys)` raises: `NameError: identifier my_key needs to be constant`

Comment: @Joe it does work fine. I think you used string keys for your hash, which is the cause for the error. The error is telling you that it needs a constant value, ie, a symbol rather than a string. I can repro the error in 2.1.5, goes away if I switch to symbol.

Comment: @Joe minor correction: the real reason for the NameError is because if you supplied a string as the first argument to Struct::new, it assumes that it's the name of the class it will create so it will attempt to convert that to a constant and fail if the string is all lower case (because constants have to be capitalized in Ruby). The fix is to either a) provide a capitalized string as a first argument (Struct.new('MyClass', *h.keys)) or use symbols for your hash's keys as ehsanul suggested.

Comment: Ran into the same issue as Joe, and had to convert my string arguments first: ```Struct.new(*h.keys.map(&:to_sym)).new(*h.values)```

Comment: Can you expand on your reply, like, why use `*`, for example?

Answer (score 19):

This is based on @elado's answer above, but using the `keyword_init` value ([Struct Documentation](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.0/Struct.html))

You could simply do this:

```
Person = Struct.new(:first_name, :last_name, :age, keyword_init: true)

person_hash = { first_name: "Foo", last_name: "Bar", age: 29 }

person = Person.new(person_hash)

=> #<struct Person first_name="Foo", last_name="Bar", age=29>
```

Comment: Note that `keyword_init: true` was only introduced in Ruby 2.5, whereas 2.4 is still within support.

Answer (score 11):

The following creates a struct from a hash in a reliable way (since hash order is not guaranteed in ruby):

```
s = Struct.new(*(k = h.keys)).new(*h.values_at(*k))
```

Answer (score 8):

Having `Hash#to_struct` is quite practical:

```
class Hash
  def to_struct
    Struct.new(*keys).new(*values)
  end
end
```

And some examples:

```
>> { a: 1, b: 2 }.to_struct
=> #<struct a=1, b=2>
>> { a: 1, b: 2 }.to_struct.a
=> 1
>> { a: 1, b: 2 }.to_struct.b
=> 2
>> { a: 1, b: 2 }.to_struct.c
NoMethodError: undefined method `c` for #<struct a=1, b=2>
```

Deep `to_struct` that works with arrays:

```
class Array
  def to_struct
    map { |value| value.respond_to?(:to_struct) ? value.to_struct : value }
  end
end

class Hash
  def to_struct
    Struct.new(*keys).new(*values.to_struct)
  end
end
```

Comment: Its good, But if its json hash `['name']`, needs to symbolize the keys.

Comment: @7urkm3n What does that even mean?

Comment: @konsolebox hash is key/value, if hash has json value then key name has to be symbolized. as i remember this. Sorry its 4yrs old thread :)

Comment: @7urkm3n Still don't get it. What is a "json hash" or a "json value". Care to give an example? As far as I know, JSON doesn't have symbols, only strings. So why the need to convert strings to symbols? JSON keys aren't symbols.

Answer (score 2):

You can convert from Hash to Struct using the following code:

```rb
Struct.new(*my_hash.keys.map(&:to_sym)).new(*my_hash.values)
```

Ensure you convert all keys to symbols, as it will error on String keys, `NameError: identifier my_key needs to be constant`

I personally recommend adding a monkey patch to the Hash class because this is such a powerful action

```
# config/initializers/core_extensions.rb

Hash.class_eval do
  def to_struct
    Struct.new(*keys.map(&:to_sym)).new(*values)
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example to map the values to the proper order of the Struct:

```
require 'securerandom'

Message = Struct.new(:to, :from, :message, :invitee)

message_params = {from: "my@email.address", to: "your@email.address",
        invitee: SecureRandom.uuid, message: "hello"}

if Message.members.sort == message_params.keys.sort
  # Do something with the return struct object here
  Message.new *Message.members.map {|k| message_params[k] } 
else
  raise "Invalid keys for Message"
end
```

Answer (score 1):

This gives a clean plain read-only object, similar to a ruby Struct but with deep conversion and extra `to_h` method to get struct at any point as Hash.

Example

```
foo = {a:{b:{c:123}}}.to_struct
foo.a.b.c # 123
foo.a.to_h # {b:{c:123}}
```

Ruby code

```
class Hash
  def to_struct
    Class.new.tap do |c|
      c.define_singleton_method(:to_h) do
        m_list = methods(false) - [:to_h]
        m_list.inject({}) do |h, m|
          h[m] = send(m)
          h[m] = h[m].to_h if h[m].class == Class
          h
        end
      end

      each do |k, v|
        v = v.to_struct if v.class == Hash
        c.define_singleton_method(k) { v }
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Not exactly the answer to a question (not a ruby Struct object), but I needed just this while looking for an answer, so I will just post the answer here.

Answer (score 1):

If you need a recursive version, here's a neat hack/solution

```rb
a_hash = {a: {b: {c: 'x'}}}
structs_inside_structs = JSON.parse(
  a_hash.to_json, object_class: OpenStruct
)
# => #<OpenStruct a=#<OpenStruct b=#<OpenStruct c="x">>>
structs_inside_structs.a.b.c
# => "x"
```

Answer (score 0):

TL;DR;

use **OpenStruct.new(hash)**

**New Better way**

```
hash = {"Name" => "Taimoor", "id" => "222", "SomeKey" => "Some value", "attributes" => {"type" => 'User', 'role' => 'manager'}}
OpenStruct.new(hash)
```

This will only convert 1st level of hash to struct. To convert nested attributes hash to struct I did this

```
hash.attributes = OpenStruct.new(hash.attributes)
```

**OLD Way**

I had a hash with string keys

```
{"Name" => "Taimoor", "id" => "222", "SomeKey" => "Some value"}
```

So I need to first convert keys to symbols `hash.keys.map(&:to_sym)` and to access those keys in the original hash, I used the `hash.with_indifferent_access` method on the hash.

```
def hash_to_struct(hash)
    Struct.new(*(k = hash.keys.map(&:to_sym)))
        .new(*hash.with_indifferent_access.values_at(*k))
end
```

Now it will work for both symbol and string type keys of the hash.

**Note:** This will convert the hash to struct at one level only. For nested hash, you need to call this method on each level of nesting.

Comment: NOTE: `OpenStruct` incurs a performance penalty compared to `Struct`. It is now recommended to use `Struct` unless you _really_ need the keys/attributes to be dynamic. See https://www.rubydoc.info/gems/rubocop/0.61.1/RuboCop/Cop/Performance/OpenStruct.

Answer (score -1):

```
require 'ds_hash'

data = {a: {b: 123 }}.to_struct

data.a.b == 123       # true
data.a   == {b: 123 } # true
```