# How create new instance of a Ruby Struct using named arguments (instead of assuming correct order of arguments)

Tags: ruby, struct

Given: Customer = Struct.new(:name, :address, :zip)

Is there a way to name the arguments instead of presuming a certain order?

The docs say do it like this:

```
joe = Customer.new("Joe Smith", "123 Maple, Anytown NC", "12345")
```

which IMO makes it too easy to switch two parameters accidentally.

I'd like to do something like this:

```
joe = Customer.new(name: "Joe Smith", address: "123 Maple, Anytown NC", zip: "12345")
```

so that the order is not important:

```
joe = Customer.new(zip: "12345", name: "Joe Smith", address: "123 Maple, Anytown NC")
```

Comment: If it doesn't have to be a struct you could consider ostruct, e.g., http://stackoverflow.com/a/11962369/438992. There are performance issues, but they don't necessarily matter.

Comment: i considered openstruct but AFAIK it does not provide the protection against accidentally mis-named keys, for example one could accidentally set namezzzz: "John doe" and it would create a new (wrong) attribute, whereas if you tried that with a Struct it would alert you by throwing an exception (as desired).

Comment: Yep, that's a definite disadvantage.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Named parameters are not (yet) possible in Ruby's `Struct` class. You can create a subclass of your own in line with this Gist: https://gist.github.com/mjohnsullivan/951668

As you know, full-fledged `Classes` can have named parameters. I'd love to learn why they aren't possible with `Structs`... I surmise that someone on the Core team has thought of this and rejected it.

Comment: The `NamedStruct` is nice although I think `*args` is not needed since you are excluding everything after the first argument. eg. `def initialize attributes` would function equivalently without having to pack them into an `Array` and `to_hash` could be simplified to `members.each_with_object({}) {|m,obj| obj[m] = self[m]}`

Comment: Good point, yes. To be clear, it's not my gist - credit where credit's due.