# Perform an opeartion within a hash

Tags: ruby

I want to perform a block operation on a hash without an iteration, smth like follows:

```
myhash = {
    foo: 'foo',
    bar: 'bar',
    baz: 'baz'
}

with myhash do 
   # operation with foo:
   # operation with bar:
   # other operations, etc
   # operation with baz:
end
```

to avoid the syntax repeating:

```
myhash[:foo]
myhash[:bar]
myhash[:baz]
# much mo keys
```

Is that possible?

Comment: It's not clear what you actually want to do. Why can't you iterate or use the hashes keys?

Comment: I suggest you to add the tag *metaprogramming*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even though as many suggested it's probably better to just stick with `myhash[:foo]`, it's possible to do what you want, but only for science sake!

```
require 'ostruct'

myhash = OpenStruct.new({
    foo: 'foo',
    bar: 'bar',
    baz: 'baz'
})

# you can do stuff like this with ostruct
myhash.foo
myhash.bar

@thing = "urgh"
thing = @thing

# every object has a built in tap method
myhash.tap { |h|
  p @thing
  h.foo + h.bar
}

# evey object has the instance_eval method
# when using instance eval, there are some trade-off
myhash.instance_eval do
  # instance variables don't work as you'd expect in there
  p @thing
  # but variables and methods do!
  p thing
  derp = 4
  p (foo * derp)
  p (baz + foo * derp)
end
```

Sorry the output is a mess, but you didn't specify what the output had to look like :)

Comment: Very clever! Yes, for the sake of science! Certainly not for the sake of showing off. :-)

Comment: Code is much better now!

Comment: Better, yes, but you edited out the clever bit: the use of `method_missing`.

Answer (score 2):

There is no way to create local variables in Ruby (1.9+); so you are stuck with using `Hash`, `OpenStruct` or `Struct`. (["Convert a `Hash` into a `Struct`"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11962192/convert-a-hash-into-a-struct)) Just use the `Hash`, it is not that big a deal.

Answer (score 1):

Not really sure if it is useful, I would just use the hash syntax, but you could do something like

```
foo, bar, baz = myhash.values_at(:foo, :bar, :baz)
```

or convert it to an `OpenStruct` :

```
h = OpenStruct.new(myhash)
```

and then you can just write

```
h.foo = h.bar + h.baz
```

Comment: actually very useful, I just realized

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

```
my_dogs = { dog1: "Bobo", dog2: "Millie", dog3: "Billy-Bob", dog4: "Erma" }

flea_ridden = my_dogs.values_at(:dog3, :dog1, :dog4)
  #=> ["Billy-Bob", "Bobo", "Erma"] 
str = "My dogs "
  #=> "My dogs " 
str << "#{flea_ridden.shift}, "
  #=> "My dogs Billy-Bob, " 
str << "#{flea_ridden.shift}, "
  #=> "My dogs Billy-Bob, Bobo, " 
str << "and "
  #=> "My dogs Billy-Bob, Bobo, and " 
str << "#{flea_ridden.shift} "
  #=> "My dogs Billy-Bob, Bobo, and Erma " 
str << "have fleas"
  #=> "My dogs Billy-Bob, Bobo, and Erma have fleas" 
puts str
  # My dogs Billy-Bob, Bobo, and Erma have fleas
```

Comment: I'd use `str = "My dogs #{flea_ridden * ', '} have fleas"` or take advantage of Active Support's [`to_sentence`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_support_core_extensions.html#extensions-to-array) to join and add " and ".

Comment: @theTinMan, I agree with your first suggestion, but I just wanted to illustrate the basic idea of constructing an array and repeatedly `shift`ing it's elements for problems of this kind. I am not familiar with `ActiveSupport`, so I can't comment on that.