# Can I make a class that presents methods and variables transparently?

Tags: ruby, lazy-loading

I'd like to do some config-file work with Ruby. Some elements of the config nominally depend on other elements, but not necessarily.

For example, when using the config, I'd like to do this:

```
require_relative "config" 
require_relative "overrides" 
dosomething_with(Config.libpath)
```

In "config", I want something like:

```
require 'ostruct'
Config = OpenStruct.new
Config.basepath = "/usr"
Config.libpath = lambda {Config.basepath + "/lib"}    # this is not quite what I want
```

In "overrides", the user might override `Config.basepath`, and I'd like Config.libpath to take the natural value. But the user might *also* override `Config.libpath` to some constant.

I'd like to be able to just say `Config.libpath` and either get the calculated value (if it hasn't been overridden) or the defined value (if it has).

Is this something I'd do with Ruby? It seems like a natural extension of how I've seen OpenStruct work.

Comment: `OpenStruct` uses `method_missing` for its magic, you might as well have a look at that if you don't have an issue with performance

Comment: be careful with OpenStruct as it consumes memory very quickly. I have experienced it myself but [See this Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1177594/ruby-struct-vs-openstruct/4137908#4137908)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about this:

```
require 'ostruct'

Config = OpenStruct.new
Config.basepath = "/usr"

def Config.libpath
  # Suggested by Nathaniel himself
  @table[:libpath] || basepath + "/lib"

  # The next alternatives require def Config.libpath=(libpath) ...
  # instance_variable_defined?(:@libpath) ? @libpath : basepath + "/lib"
  # or 
  # @libpath || basepath + "/lib" , depending on your needings
end

# Needed only if @table[:libpath] is not used
# def Config.libpath=(libpath)
#   @libpath = libpath
# end

# Default basepath, default libpath
p Config.libpath #=> "/usr/lib"

# custom basepath, default libpath
Config.basepath = "/var"
p Config.libpath #=> "/var/lib"

# Custom libpath
Config.libpath = '/lib'
p Config.libpath #=> "/lib"
```

Comment: Just what I was looking for! I peeked at the source of OpenStruct, and it seems to work to use `@table[:libpath]` instead of `@libpath`, and then I don't need to define the `libpath=` method.

Comment: Oh yes, I looked it too once in the past, you reminded me it uses @table, I update the answer =)