# Rails edit serialized JSON data

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a column that stores JSON data. I don't know how to show it when it is on Edit state.

```
 serialize :value, JSON

 = f.fields_for :value do |ff|
    .form-group
      = ff.label :short  
      = ff.text_field :short, class: 'form-control'
    .form-group
      = ff.label :long
      = ff.text_field :long, class: 'form-control'
```

Answer (score 30, accepted):

In place of

`= f.fields_for :value do |ff|`

please use the following code:

`= f.fields_for :value, OpenStruct.new(@object.value) do |ff|`

You will need to replace `@object` with your model object.

Comment: Welcome! To know more about OpenStruct in ruby please take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1177594/ruby-struct-vs-openstruct :)

Comment: You can also use `f.object` to reference the model object in the `OpenStruct` instead of making another fixed reference to your model object (in this case, `@object`).

Comment: be careful with `OpenStruct`. afaik, using it at runtime [clears the vm's method cache](https://mensfeld.pl/2015/04/ruby-global-method-cache-invalidation-impact-on-a-single-and-multithreaded-applications/), resulting in performance penalties.