# What is meant by Context in Synchronization Context

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, async-await

> One aspect of SynchronizationContext is that it provides a way to queue a unit of work to a context. Note that this unit of work is queued to a context rather than a specific thread.

What exactly does "context" mean?
What is the difference between context and a thread.?

Comment: Context is just a wrapper around related things.

Comment: @SarveshMishra Can you please elaborate it for me :p

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12240548/2613020

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12240844/2613020

Comment: This shouldn't be asked here, there are blogs and a wealth of information on the internet that describes it in detail